# How to display table result on custom page webform in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, webforms

How to display table result in webform on custom page? Only result page for custom role.

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom module and code in it :

create a hook menu with role authorisation :

```
function MYMODULENAME_menu(){
    $items['my/custom/path'] = array(
        'title' => t('Results'),
        'page callback' => 'mycallback',
        'access arguments' => array('role_name'),  // 'access callback' => user_has_role('role_name'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
      );
   return $items;
}
```

create callback :

```
function mycallback(){
// get your data from database or what you want
// your code ... $datas = [...]

// construct lines 
$rows = array();
foreach($datas as $data){
  $rows[] = array($data['title1'], $data['title2']);
}

return  theme('table',
        array(
          'header' => array('Title 1','Title 2'),
          'rows' => $rows
        ));
}
```

Annexes :

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x

Answer (score 0):

Use views module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/views

When you are creating the view for "Show" option select "Webform submissions" instead of default "Content" value. Then you can tune your view as usual - create page view or block view, what ever you need.

And later, when you continue editing that view for "Format" option select "Table" (if it's not already set, as default value).